# vb.net If condition in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to use vb.net If condition in grid view item template in aspx page. I tried below code but it was not working as expected.

```
<ItemTemplate>
 <%If ddlstatus.SelectedValue.ToLower = "failed" Then%>        
    <asp:HyperLink  ID="hlfilepath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH")    NavigateUrl ='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH") ></asp:HyperLink>
    <% Else %>
          <asp:HyperLink  ID="filepath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH")></asp:HyperLink>
    <% End If%>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Exactly what was happening when you ran it?

Comment: <ItemTemplate><%If ddlstatus.SelectedValue.ToLower = "failed" Then%>        
    <asp:HyperLink  ID="hlfilepath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH")    NavigateUrl ='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH") ></asp:HyperLink><% Else %>
<asp:HyperLink  ID="filepath" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FILE_PATH")></asp:HyperLink>
    <% End If%>
 </ItemTemplate>

Comment: I am trying to add Hyper link to my itemtemplate based on if condition

Comment: Thanks I was able to resolve it